# Killing grass with cardboard

Tags: grass, planting

I am considering growing a garden on what is now grass and am considering how to get rid of the grass. One method I have become aware of is to lay cardboard on the grass and wait. How long does this take? I like in Mississippi in zone 7b/8a.

Are there any other methods that might be preferable to the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this takes about a season or two to be fully effective (I am also in a zone 8). Less than that and the grass seems to grow back.

Since you are planning on turning this into a garden, I would recommend covering the cardboard with compost (or perhaps partially composted material). This will have the benefit of helping the cardboard compost faster (so you don’t have to remove when done) and you will already have some compost in the location for when you decide to start planting.

Answer (score 1):

Black plastic sheet/film , is much more effective. Cardboard blocks light ,plants yellow and die in a month or more. Black plastic cooks them quickly ,if you have sun. It is also supposed to sterilize the soil, more or less. I have accidentally killed lawn in 2 days,although in that short time the roots can come back .

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm in the process of adding black plastic to my garden to be.